How can I fix py2neo_error?
enter image description here
I encounter a py2neo error.
I try to uninstall the py2neo library, then reinstall it.
The official document display that the py2neo library's maintain is terminated in 2021. Should I change to use the official library neo4j?

I would recommend that you switch to some other library, since the author of py2neo is no longer supporting it. For example, you may want to use the neo4j python driver.
